# Python - how to implement a custom class compatible with NumPy functions?

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy, interface

I am trying to implement my own custom class to store data. I want to make it compatible with NumPy, so that I can call NumPy functions on it like this:

```
np.sin(my_object)
```

I know that there is a dictionary called `__array_interface__`, however I am getting lots of strange errors when trying to use it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class TDF:
    __array_interface__ = {'typestr': '|i1', 'version': 1}

    def __init__(self):
        self.ddata = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])
        self.shape = self.ddata.shape

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.ddata)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.ddata)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.ddata.__getitem__(key)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tdf1 = TDF()
    tdf = np.sin(tdf1)
```

The code above gives me a run-time error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What am I missing? 
On the other hand the source code for pandas (which classes are NumPy compatible) does not explicitly use the **array_interface** dict...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple fix would be to implement

```
def __array__(self):
    return self.ddata
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes - that is what was needed. And if you want to have the result of a numpy function be of your custom type, you also have to add the method __array_wrap__.

Comment: And sometimes `__array_prepare__` too. Coming soon to a numpy near you: `__array_ufunc__`, which does a better job of what `__array_wrap__` does

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the data you stored in the object. The variable `tdf1` is just the TDF instance, but the data is stored in `tdf1.ddata`. Try calling `np.sin(tdf1.ddata)`

Comment: very well. That is indeed the fix

Comment: But the whole point is to access the data stored in the object seamlessly, without directly pointing to it. When you use numpy functions on pandas objects, you do not need to specify the variable that pandas stores data internally

Comment: @Tomasz R: Try `def __array__(self): return np.array(self.ddata)`

Comment: @stovfl can you explain this. I am curious, I tried Tomoasz R's implementation with this addition and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I have tried this and it works for me. My `class` inherited from `(object)` this is different from Tomoasz. It's the same as #Eric has proposed.

Comment: @stovfl That what I was doing, but with Thomasz R's example it was still failing. Stripped down example with only `__init__` and `__array__` worked. Gonna have to ask about this one.

Comment: @Grr: If you have a `__array_interface__` attribut, `__array__` is never called.
But, realized this is not what @Tomasz R want, it's only TypeCasting from `pandas.column` to `np.array`.
As for now I think it's the nearest solution to come.

Comment: Thanks, all. Yes, __array__ is enough and it must not be put together with __array_interface__. And if you want the returned value to be of your custom type, you have to also implement __array_wrap__