# How to make custom Python classes compatible with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a class:

```
class Quantity:
    def __init__(self, value, units):
        self.value = value
        self.units = units
```

The class is quite a bit more involved than this, but it is not relevant for this question.

I want this class to be able to do the following:

```
a = Quantity
b = list[Quantity]
np.[mathematical function](a) -> np.[mathematical function](a.value)
np.[mathematical function](b) -> np.[mathematical function]([e.value for e in b])

# e.g.
np.sin(a) -> np.sin(a.value)
np.sin([a, a]) -> np.sin([a.value, a.value])
```

According to the documentation we can use `__array_ufunc__` or `__array_function__`:

```
def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *args, **kwargs):
    out = []
    for a in args:
        if isinstance(a, self.__class__):
            out.append(a.value):
        else:
            out.append(a)
    return ufunc(out, kwagrs)
```

This does indeed work for the case `np.[mathematical function](Quantity)`, but trying to input a list returns the error:

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Quantity which has no callable [mathematical function] method
```

On the other hand, defining a function `def sqrt(self): np.sqrt(self.value)` makes the *specific* function work, even with a list .i.e `np.sqrt([Quantity])` works fine in this case, as well as `np.sqrt(Quantity)`, the issue this time is each separate function requires a separate definition.

Does anyone know of a way that generally `np.[func]([Quantity])` can be defined as `np.[func]([Quantity.value])` without individually defining each function?

Comment: this post seems to be a duplicate of [Python - how to implement a custom class compatible with NumPy functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493256/python-how-to-implement-a-custom-class-compatible-with-numpy-functions)

Comment: `np.sqrt([Quantity])` converts the list into an object dtype array, and then does the equivalent of `np.array([i.sqrt() for i in the_array])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research and testing, the only way to make it work with both, without implementing `self.__array__` (which adds compatibility for any function, even those you don't want), the only way to do this is to manually define each function you want to work and leave the rest undefined.